# Avoid titles at the bottom of pages

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I am currently learning how to properly write in MS Word. I want to avoid titles at the bottom of my pages. After looking in the internet, I tried modifying the style of my titles and the whole text. However it does not work. The titles are still at the bottom of the page.

To illustrate here is a screenshot of the modifications I made for one of the titles and another with the output.

Screenshot of the modification for the style:
[image: screenshot of the modification for the style]

The problem:
[image: the problem]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you indicate what you have tried? We might give the same answers that have proven unsuccessful for you. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1645519/edit) your question to include the steps already tried.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to headings split from their subject? The built-in headings are designed to stick with the following paragraph. Do not use the Enter key for spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Headers and Footers  (Word, Insert Ribbon).

A blank new Word Document does not have top and bottom titles.

Make sure you did not edit your Word Template to include headers and footers.

You can replace the normal template with the default template.

[Default Word Template](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/restore-ms-office-normal-template-63456.html)

Double-click the now-visible "AppData" folder to open it and then open the "Microsoft\Templates" folder

Locate the "normal.dotm" file inside the Templates folder, select it, hold "Shift" and press "Delete." Click "Yes" to permanently delete the normal template file.

Launch Microsoft Word to create a new, default normal template.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your screenshot over to this forum. You are doing things right. (See my comment to your question).

Chances are good that you have used the Enter key for spacing or you have multiple paragraphs all formatted for keep with next and keep lines together. Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill has an [excellent page examining this](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/BottomLine.htm). Here is a [Google translation](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=fr&u=http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/BottomLine.htm) of that page.

It can help if you display the non-printing formatting characters. The keyboard shortcut for this is: `Ctrl`+`*` or `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `8`. This is a toggle setting.

Comment: Have you had a chance to digest my answer?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for the corrections! I tried again to write a text and it worked: This time I put the text as body text and titles as titles.  There was no title at the end of my pages.

Comment: I am glad to have helped. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers